# Product tabs are not showing in product detail page

Tags: magento2, product, magento2.4, category-products

product tabs are not showing on the product detail page and reviews are coming down to Description.
I had created a custom tab and this one also does not show [image]

http://18.169.225.50/calacatta-matt-white-marble-effect-porcelain-tile-600x600.html
Magento version 2.4.3
For reference please find the attached image.

Answer (score 2):

Open Product in mangento backend catalog -> Products -> select the product ->Design
Layout -> No layout updates
Display Product Options In -> Product Info Column
For reference please find the attached image.
[image]

Comment: Perfect Thanks Allot It worked

Comment: It's not a proper solution to do this thing for every product

Answer (score 0):

You could try updating "Default Product Layout" to "No layout updates", as per https://docs.magento.com/user-guide/design/page-layout.html

You may need to clear cache. This should not affect existing products.

The issue could be caused if the theme is Porto and Pagebuilder is disabled.