# Magento 2.4.3 product view Details, More Information and Reviews not showing as tabs

Tags: magento2, product, tabs

I have magento 2.4.3 installed and working properly. However I am not able to see the Details, More Information and Reviews as Tabs on the product View. They are displyed as different blocks one on top of each other (very ugly especially if you have multiple review on the product).

If I deploy the sample data, the tabs appear below each of the product picture. If I add a new product, the tabs are being displayed properly. I have tried multiple layouts with no avail.

I am not trying to add any custom tabs here, just want to replicate the default expected behavior.

Thank you for your help.

Answer (score 0):

1. Check if any JS errors.
2. Check if your product description has some html/css and is some how the reason for this issue.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you for the feedback.

1.I already checked for js errors and in fact I have only one js error but it seems unrelated to that issue. I have the same error on my other installation with sample data installed. Here is the error /en_CA/Magento_PageBuilder/js/resource/vimeo/player.js.map: HTTP error: status code 404, net::ERR_HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE_FAILURE
2.My description contains just text. I am using page builder: Row + text element. I tested simple html but did not fix the issue. I created the same on the other installation with sample data and itr works. Somehow, the html code for the tabs are not generated. It seems something is missing and when I install the sample data the tabs works fine.
3.In the Design section of the product, I tried No Layout Updates + Product Info Column but did not change anything.

Comment: revert to the default theme and check first if the issue exist.

Comment: I already tried Luma, Blank and with no theme at all. Same result. It only works if I deploy the sample data. I even did a fresh installation of Magento 2.4.3 without success.

Comment: Hi, it works now... Thanks for your help. I got it from the follwoing post where some user had the same issue and find a way to fix it: https://magento.stackexchange.com/a/349428/101261